# Cygwin/Babun: ssh-host-config error with local ADMINSTRATORS and/or SYSTEM

Tags: ssh, cygwin, sshd, local

executing `ssh-host-config -y` shows following output:

```
....
*** Info: called 'sshd'.
*** Info: For more info on privilege separation read /usr/share/doc/openssh/README.privsep.
*** Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) yes
*** Warning: It appears that you do not have entries for the local
*** Warning: ADMINISTRATORS and/or SYSTEM sids in /etc/group.
*** Warning:
*** Warning: Use the 'mkgroup' utility to generate them or allow "db"
*** Warning: search of group accounts in /etc/nsswitch.conf
*** Warning:
*** Warning: It appears that you do not have an entry for the local
*** Warning: ADMINISTRATORS (group) and/or SYSTEM sids.
*** Warning:
*** Warning: Use the 'mkpasswd' utility to generate it or allow "db"
*** Warning: search of passwd accounts in /etc/nsswitch.conf
*** Warning:
*** ERROR: Problem with LocalSystem or Adminstrator IDs
```

Here's these two messages again but reformatted (for easier full text search):

- It appears that you do not have entries for the local ADMINISTRATORS and/or SYSTEM sids in /etc/group.

  - Use the 'mkgroup' utility to generate them or allow "db" search of group accounts in /etc/nsswitch.conf
- It appears that you do not have an entry for the local ADMINISTRATORS (group) and/or SYSTEM sids.

  - Use the 'mkpasswd' utility to generate it or allow "db" search of passwd accounts in /etc/nsswitch.conf

`net user` gives me following:

```
Benutzerkonten für \\xy

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            DefaultAccount           Gast
me
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Crosspost here: https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/213#issuecomment-505795795